# Masking wildcard SSL cetificate with top-level domain

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, multi-tenant

I'm in a situation where I'm using a multi-tenancy application. Within this application each customer gets a unique subdomain looking like this:
**https://customer1.apps.demo.com**

We use a wildcard SSL certificate to secure ***.apps.demo.com**.

So far so good.

The issue arises when the customers wants to use their top-level domain (**http://customer1.com**) instead of our unique subdomain (**https://customer1.apps.demo.com**
). I've been looking at domain masking but that breaks SSL. Is there really any other way? Right now I'm looking at using iframes but really want to avoid that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostname of the URL must match the certificate subject(s) and there is no way around it. And you will not be able to get a certificate which includes the customers domain because you own it. This only leaves the following options:

- The customer provides you with a certificate you should use. In this case you either have to have a separate IP address for the customer or you need to use [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) which is supported by all current browsers but still sometimes has problems outside of the browsers (i.e. mobile apps, scripts...).
- The customer sets a reverse proxy with its own certificate and handles the forwarding to your domain by itself.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it's possible to have a wildcard certificate and limitless single certificate for customer top-level domain on the same server/ip? That's when SNI comes to use?

Comment: @Rovdjuret: technically it does not matter on which server /IP (and on how much) a certificate is deployed, but you should check for any restrictions done by the certificate issuer. SNI is needed if you don't have enough IP addresses, i.e. need to deploy different certificates on the same IP address.

Comment: Thanks once again, you rock! :)